# error using function mexopencv.make

Tags: matlab, opencv

I came across this error while trying to use opencv in matlab. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Error using mex
mexopencv_features2d.cpp
c:\mexopencv-master\mexopencv-master\include\mexopencv.hpp(88) : error C2039: 'DIST_USER' : is not a member of 'cv'
c:\mexopencv-master\mexopencv-master\include\mexopencv.hpp(88) : error C2065: 'DIST_USER' : undeclared identifier
c:\mexopencv-master\mexopencv-master\include\mexopencv.hpp(89) : error C2039: 'DIST_L1' : is not a member of 'cv'
...
C:\mexopencv-master\mexopencv-master\include\mexopencv_features2d.hpp(78) : error C2039: 'AGAST_7_12d' : is not a member of
'cv'
C:\mexopencv-master\mexopencv-master\include\mexopencv_features2d.hpp(78) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100;
stopping compilation



Error in mexopencv.make (line 153)
        if ~opts.dryrun, eval(cmd); end
```

Comment: Raise an issue on the `mexopencv` homepage Github repo instead.  You'll have a better chance of Kota Yamaguchi replying to you directly: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues

Comment: It sounds like you're compiling against the wrong version of OpenCV. Make sure your version matches the mexopencv build instructions.